# Idiomatic Clojure equivalent of this Python code?

Tags: python, clojure

I wrote a simple stack-based virtual machine in Python, and now I'm trying to rewrite it in Clojure, which is proving difficult as I don't have much experience with Lisp. [This Python snippet](http://pastebin.com/SAcnAxti) processes the bytecode, which is represented as a list of tuples like so:

```
[("label", "entry"),
 ("load", 0),
 ("load", 1),
 ("add",),
 ("store", 0)]
```

Or in Clojure:

```
[[:label :entry]
 [:load 0]
 [:load 1]
 [:add]
 [:store 0]]
```

When a Function object loads the bytecode, every "label" tuple is processed specially to mark that position, while every other tuple stays in the final bytecode. I would assume that the Clojure equivalent of this function would involve a fold, but I'm not sure how to do that in an elegant or idiomatic way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Reading that Python snippet, it looks like you want the eventual output to look like

```
{:code [[:load 0]
        [:load 1]
        [:add]
        [:store 0]]
 :labels {:entry 0}}
```

It's much easier to write the code once you have a firm description of the goal, and indeed this is a pretty simple reduce. There are a number of stylistically-different ways to write the reductor, but this way seems easiest to read, for me.

```
(defn load [asm]
  (reduce (fn [{:keys [code labels]} [op arg1 & args :as instruction]]
            (if (= :label op)
              {:code code
               :labels (assoc labels arg1 (count code))}
              {:code (conj code instruction)
               :labels labels}))
          {:code [], :labels {}},
          asm))
```

#### Edit

This version supports a `name` argument, and simplifies the reduction step by not repeating elements that don't change.

```
(defn load [name asm]
  (reduce (fn [program [op arg1 :as instruction]]
            (if (= :label op)
              (assoc-in program [:labels arg1] (count (:code program)))
              (update-in program [:code] conj instruction)))
          {:code [], :labels {}, :name name},
          asm))
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't guarantee that this is idiomatic Clojure, but this is a functional version of your Python code, which should at least get you pretty close.

```
(def prog [
 [:label :entry]
 [:load 0]
 [:load 1]
 [:add]
 [:store 0]])

(defn parse [stats]
    (let [
        f (fn [[out-stats labels pc] stat]
            (if (= :label (first stat))
                [out-stats (conj labels [(second stat) pc]) pc]
                [(conj out-stats stat) labels (+ 1 pc)]))
        init [[] {} 0]
        ]
        (reduce f init stats)))

(println (parse prog))
```

So I think you're correct that a fold is what you want. All functional folds walk a collection and "reduce" that collection into a single value. However, nothing says that the resulting single value can't also be a collection or, as in this case, a collection of collections.

In our case, we are going to use the three-parameter version of reduce - this lets us provide an initial accumulator value. We need to do this because we are going to track a lot of state as we iterate across the collection of bytecodes, and the two-parameter version pretty much requires that your accumulator be similar to the items in the list. (c.f. `(reduce + [1 2 3 4])`  )

When working with a functional fold, you need to think in terms of what you are accumulating, and how each element in the input collection contributes to that accumulation. If you look at your Python code, there are three values that can be updated on each turn of the loop:

- The output statements (`self.code`)
- The label mapping (`self.labels`)
- The program counter (`pc`)

Nothing else is written during the loop. So, our accumulator value will need to store those three values.

That previous bit is the most important part.

Once you have that, the rest should be pretty easy. We need an initial accumulator value, which has no code, no label mappings, and a PC that starts at 0. On each iteration, we will update the accumulator in one of two ways:

- Add a new label mapping
- Add a new output program statement, and increment the program counter

And now, the output:

```
[[[:load 0] [:load 1] [:add] [:store 0]] 
 {:entry 0}
 4]
```

That's a 3-element vector. The first element is the program. The second element is the label mappings. The third element is the next PC value. Now, you might modify parse to only produce two values; that's not an unreasonable thing to do. There are reasons you might not want to do it, but that's more an issue of API design than anything. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader.

I should also mention that, initially, I had omitted the let block and had simply inlined the named values. I decided to pull them out to hopefully increase readability. Again, I don't know which is more idiomatic. That might be more of a per-project convention.

Finally, I don't know if monads have really taken off in the Clojure community, but you could also create a monad for bytecode parsing, and define the operations "add-statement" and "add-label" to be values in that monad. This would greatly increase the set-up complexity, but would simplify the actual parsing code. In fact, it would allow your parsing code to look fairly procedural, which may or may not be a good thing. (don't worry, it's still functional and side-effect free; monads just let you hide plumbing.) If your Python sample is pretty representative of the kind of data you need to process, then monads are almost certainly unnecessary overhead. On the other hand, if you actually have to manage much more state than indicated by your sample, then monads might help to keep you sane.

Comment: I should also mention that I replied [on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/o79q0/re_idiomatic_equivalent_of_this_python_code/), but was directed here.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn make-function [name code]
  (let [[code labels] (reduce (fn [[code labels] inst]
                                (if (= (first inst) :label)
                                  [code (assoc labels (second inst) (count code))]
                                  [(conj code inst) labels]))
                              [[] {}] ;; initial state of code and labels
                              code)]
    {:name name, :code code :labels labels}))
```

It's a bit wide for my liking, but not *too* bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you a general solution for these kind of problems.

Most loops can be done effortlessly with a strait forward *map*, *filter* or *reduce*, and if your data structure is recursive, naturally the loop will be a recursion.

Your loop, however, is a different kind of loop. Your loop accumulates a result -- which would suggests using *reduce* -- but the loop also carries a local variable along (*pc*), so it's not a strait reduce.

It's a reasonably common kind of loop. If this was [Racket](http://racket-lang.org), I would use [for/fold1](http://planet.plt-scheme.org/package-source/untyped/unlib.plt/3/24/planet-docs/unlib/for.html#%28form._%28%28planet._for..ss._%28untyped._unlib..plt._3._23%29%29._for/fold1%29%29), but since it's not, we will have to shoehorn your loop onto *reduce*.

Let's define a function called *load* which returns two things, the processed code and the processed labels. I will also use a helper function called *is-label?*.

```
(defn load [asm]
  (defn is-label? [x] (= (first x) :label))
  {:code <<< CODE GOES HERE >>>

   :labels
   <<< CODE GOES HERE >>>
  })
```

Right now, your loop does two things, it processes the code, and it processes the labels. As much as possible, I try to keep loops to a single task. It makes them easier to understand, and it often reveals opportunities for using the simpler loop constructs.

To get the code, we simply need to remove the labels. That's a call to *filter*.

```
  {:code (filter (complement is-label?) asm)

   :labels
   <<< CODE GOES HERE >>>
  }
```

Reduce normally has only one accumulator, but your loop needs two: the result, and the local variable *pc*. I will package these two into a vector which will be immediately deconstructed by the body of the loop. The two slots of the vector will be my two local variables.

The initial values for these two variables appear as the 2nd argument to *reduce*.

```
   (first
    (reduce
     (fn [[result, pc] inst]

        << MORE CODE >>

     [{} 0] asm))
```

(Note how the initial values for the variables are placed far from their declaration. If the body is long this can be hard to read. That's the problem Racket's *for/fold1* solves.)

Once *reduce* returns, I call *first* to discard to the local variable *pc* and keep just the result.

Filling the body of the loop is straight forward. If the instruction is a label, *assoc* into the result, otherwise increase *pc* by one. In either case, I construct a vector containing new values for all the local variables.

```
     (fn [[result, pc] [_ arg :as inst]]
       (if (is-label? inst)
         [(assoc result arg pc) pc]
         [result (inc pc)]))
```

This technique can be used to convert any accumulator-with-locals loop into a *reduce*. Here's the full code.

```
(defn load [asm]
  (defn is-label? [x] (= (first x) :label))
  {:code (filter (complement is-label?) asm)

   :labels
   (first
    (reduce
     (fn [[result, pc] [_ arg :as inst]]
       (if (is-label? inst)
         [(assoc result arg pc) pc]
         [result (inc pc)]))
     [{} 0] asm))})
```